# How do I capture a video in a tensor4d on tensorflow.js?

Tags: tensorflow, webcam-capture, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to build a web application that captures a series of images that need to be evenly spaced. I've noticed that the `capture()` function on `tf.data.webcam()` takes a variable amount of time. Is there a workaround to capture images evenly spaced in time OR capture a video in a tensor4d element so that I can get evenly spaced slices?

Comment: how variable is the time between the pictures ? How are you calling tf.data.webcam ? You can possibly show your code as well